# "addTarget" action function of UIButton not called (strikethrough)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, addtarget

I have a `UIButton` within a `UITableViewCell`. When I call `addTarget` on the button and attempt to put a function in, the autocomplete has the function crossed out with a white line (see first image). Xcode still allows me to put the function in and run the app; however, when the button is tapped the function isn't called.

[image]

Button initialization:

```
private let infoButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        button.setImage(Images.sizeGuide, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

Function (infoButtonPressed):

```
@objc private func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Button Pressed")
    }
```

Because I reuse this cell multiple times and only one of these cells needs to have this button, I have a variable that dictates whether or not to show the button:

```
var hasInfoButton: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if hasInfoButton {
                setupInfoButton()
            }
        }
    }
```

The function that is called above simply sets up the button using `autoLayout`. Something to mention: when I tried calling `addTarget` in this function, the app crashed with `Unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

The `tableView` in which this is embedded in is only static and displays data. Therefore, `allowSelection` and `allowsMultipleSelection` are both set to `false`.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Try removing the `private` modifier from your method.

Comment: @Sweeper still does not work. The method is still crossed out in autocomplete.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is crossed out, is it still not called when you click the button?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, the function still isn't called. I set `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` to `true` and the image responds visually when I tap it - the function just isn't called.

Comment: I just realised, why `primaryActionTriggered`? It should be `touchUpInside`.

Comment: @Sweeper oh, I am sorry! I was following what another answer said on a different post and forgot to change it back to `touchUpInside`. Regardless, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `(_ sender: UIButton)` the method should just be:

```
@objc func infoButtonPressed() {
    print("button pressed")
}
```

EDIT:
The button initializer is also a little strange. The way I generally go about this kind of thing is like this:

```
let button = UIButton()

private func configureButton() {
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        button.setImage(Images.sizeGuide, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Then call `configureButton()` in `viewDidLoad()`